# How to get the Quip workspace name from the code of Live App?

Tags: liveapps, quip

Currently I'm developing the live app to integrate my service into Quip.
I need to interact with Quip API from the back-end of my application.

Every Quip workspace has it's own API applications with Client ID/Secrets.

> "Quip workspace" - I mean [workspace].quip.com

So my application need to know which token it should use to access to Quip Public API.

I'm looking for a way to get the Quip workspace name from Live app code to send it to my application backend.

I found the domain name in `quip.elements.getSitePreferences()` properties via console (http://take.ms/MgX19), but have no idea how to get it from that properties.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not currently possible with the Live Apps API, since there isn't an API call that gives you the domain.

Comment: So, if the live app don't know in which workspace it works, how the third-party services which are integrating to Quip should know the exactly those credentials to work with Quip REST API?

Answer (score 1):

I had success with `document.referrer`.